# How do I join multiple columns into one in footable?

Tags: javascript, json, footable

I have a FooTable that gets a part number returned as 3 separate cells. I'd like to combine them into one cell but I'm unsure of how the formatter and parser work for FooTable. my table html is just an empty table, everything is handledin the javascript. How would I go about doing this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(function($){
               $('.table').footable({
                "expandFirst": false,
                "columns": [
                    { "name": "PartID", "title":"PartID", "visible":false },
                    {"formatter": function(value){
                        return //I'm thinking this is where the code would go to join the next 3 columns? in the format ##.###.##
                    }},
                    { "name": "PartCategory", "title": "PC" },
                    { "name": "PartNumber1", "title": "PN1" },
                    { "name": "PartNumber2", "title": "PN2",  },
                    { "name": "PartName", "title": "Name",  },
                    { "name": "DescShort", "title": "Description",  },
                    { "name": "SupplierName", "title": "Supplier", },
                    { "name": "SupplierPartNumber", "title": "Supplier Part #",  }
                ],
                "rows": $.getJSON("../dist/scripts/testGetParts.php")
               });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `data-hide="all"` to the first two columns of those three:

```
{ "name": "", "title": "",  data-hide="all"},
{ "name": "", "title": "",  data-hide="all"},
{ "name": "Part Info", "title": "Part Information" }
```

Merge those in `php` (which you are good at) and just show them in here as one col in your `dataset` and Voila.

The simpler version if you can change the `dataset` is to not add those `columns` at all.

Another option if you cannot/don't want to change your server side code is to get the data and change it `js` and then bind them to rows afterwards.

```
var rows = $.getJSON("../dist/scripts/testGetParts.php");
foreach(row in rows) {
    //merge those cols here in the third one
}
```

And then:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('.table').footable({
    "expandFirst": false,
    "columns": [
        { "name": "PartID", "title":"PartID", "visible":false },
        { "name": "PartCategory", "title": "PC", data-hide="all" },
        { "name": "PartNumber1", "title": "PN1", data-hide="all"},
        { "name": "Part Info", "title": "Part information" },
        { "name": "PartName", "title": "Name",  },
        { "name": "DescShort", "title": "Description",  },
        { "name": "SupplierName", "title": "Supplier", },
        { "name": "SupplierPartNumber", "title": "Supplier Part #",  }
    ],
    "rows": rows
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm still sure you can do this with the Formatter, however this solution will work just fine, ideally you'd change your data format as suggested, but you might need separate fields somewhere else.

Comment: I ended up modifying my php to add in a concatenated column. I still feel like it's kind of hacky and i would like to eventually figure it out in formatter but this will work for now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you do it persay in footable, in kendo you would do it like so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(function($){
           $('.table').footable({
            "expandFirst": false,
            "columns": [
                { "name": "PartID", "title":"PartID", "visible":false },
                { "title":"PartNumber", formatter: function(data){
                    return data.PartCategory +"."+ data.PartNumber1 +"." + PartNumber2;
                }},
                { "name": "PartName", "title": "Name",  },
                { "name": "DescShort", "title": "Description",  },
                { "name": "SupplierName", "title": "Supplier", },
                { "name": "SupplierPartNumber", "title": "Supplier Part #",  }
            ],
            "rows": $.getJSON("../dist/scripts/testGetParts.php")
           });
        });
    });
```

Comment: That is header data you cannot access the data which is coming from $.getJSON at the rows section in header

Comment: Directly from their documentation: To be able to provide a different value to what is supplied in the cells contents you apply the data-value attribute directly on the cell and let the column formatter turn the value into the cell contents.

Comment: fyi I didn't downvote you, as I thought that might work as well, since DataTables also does something similar.

Comment: Did it do anything? throw an error in your log? can you whip up a jsfiddle? also try setting a breakppoint in that formatter function and see what data comes back as.

Comment: `data` was not defined so I tried `value` and i got the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'PartCategory' of null`. I will try and get a jfiddle example running here in a couple minutes.